# A large part of human learning is visual, is it possible to teach someone who is blind mathematics up to Calc II?

Tags: calculus, education

I wanted to post the statistic on how much of learning is visual but those studies aren't backed up well (the studies state approximately 65% of learning is visual).

I am asking this question here on the the Stack Exchange for Mathematics because if anyone knows math best and the ways to teach it, it's mathematicians.

Comment: A [similar question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/how-do-blind-people-learn-mathematics) has been asked on the Math Educators Stack Exchange. Actually, there's a number of questions related to blindness, but that's probably the most relevant.

Comment: It is surely very difficult to teach blind persons mathematics, but I think it is possible, if the person has the necessary mental fitness. There are blind people who can play chess very well without being specialized to blind chess ( where the player just does not see the board but usually is not blind ). In the last years of his life , Euler was almost blind, but still could contribute valuable results.

Comment: I remember Luc Illusie had a blind student.

Comment: I’ve done it. I’ve also taught beginning graduate level linear algebra to a blind student. Both students did well.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott That's amazing. Did you find it difficult as a teacher?

Comment: @K.defaoite: The main thing was to keep firmly in mind that I couldn’t rely on gestures and pointing for much of anything, and yes, this took a bit of concentration in calculus, especially when we were discussing graphing! I also wanted to work in the extra verbal description as naturally as possible, so that it wouldn’t be terribly obtrusive. The other course was much easier: my students, including the blind one, were high school teachers themselves.